# json data send using post in android

Tags: android, json, gps

i want to send my data in form of json to server using post method in android.

here is my format |data1|data2|data3|<>|data11|data22|data33

hope some example since i difficult to catch the procedure of post method.

Anyidea?

Edit:

my json format |data1|data2|data3|<>|data11|data22|data33|

where each data is a plain text (text get from database)

how can create it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post seems to talk about just that.

[Post JSON Using Android And HttpClient](http://localtone.blogspot.com/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html)

Edit: I saw your reply. Here's how. Hope this does the trick :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("<path to json file>");
    FileInputStream fis;
    String json = "";

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream  dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

      // dis.available() returns 0 if the file does not have more lines.
      while (dis.available() != 0) {
         json += dis.readLine();
      }

      // dispose all the resources after using them.
      fis.close();
      bis.close();
      dis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Essentially after this you would create the string entity to send

```
StringEntity st = new StringEntity(json.toString());
```

Then just follow the steps in that link

Haha, edit for your 2nd question: Just create a string with the text from the database. Thats all there is to it. Then create a StringEntity like the one above.

Comment: thx for link, i had a glance on it n i encounter problem about my json creation.? 
how can i create that ? do i need to pout { } ?

Comment: thx manish burman for ur edited answer, sorry now i just edit my question hope u can have a glance on it thx